# Need help with this ODE $y' + \frac{y}{x} \log y = \frac{y}{x^2} \cdot (\log y)^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' + \frac{y}{x} \log y = \frac{y}{x^2} \cdot (\log y)^2$$

I'm completely stumped. It's not linear neither could I make a substitution to make it linear. I tried $z = \log y$ which didn't help to make it linear in $z$. I verified it's not exact, and I cannot find any integrating factors which are only functions of $x$ or $y$.

What type of an ODE is it if it is of a certain type? How do I approach it? I've no idea or otherwise I'm not familiar with the technique needed to solve it. Please, I only need a hint.

Comment: Change of function $u=\log (y)$.

Comment: @JJacquelin I did that. I mentioned it in the details. Let me try further again.

Comment: @JohnathanG Then make a new substitution $v = u/x$ to get the ODE $xv' = v^{2} - 2v$ which you can solve by separation.

Comment: The ODE obtained is of the homogeneous kind. So, change : $v=xu$ leading to a separable ODE.

Comment: Thank you.  Shouldn't have missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Divide the differential equation by $y$ on both sides and set $\log y =z$. You will find that it will become a first order (Bernoulli) differential equation in $z$.

$$\frac {dz}{dx}+\frac {z}{x}=\frac {z^2}{x^2}$$

Then take $p=z^{1-2}=z^{-1} $ and $\frac {dp}{dx}=-\frac {1}{z^2}\cdot\frac {dz}{dx}$

So we get $$-\frac {dp}{dx}+\frac {p}{x}=\frac {1}{x^2}$$

Now this is a first order linear differential equation.

Solving this, you will get 
$$p=\frac {1}{2x}+kx$$ where $k$ is a constant.

Comment: I did get this. But, I didn't know about Bernoulli equation. I shall look it up.  Thank you

Comment: @JohnathanG  Check the update please. See if it helps.

Comment: You're welcome.